# Empty tooltip for stack exchange site icon in edit email settings

Tags: bug, status-completed, email

I see an empty tooltip for the stack exchange site's icon in the your communities of the edit email settings. For other sites I can see the relevant tooltip.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the heads up. Stack Exchange should never have been rendered there in the first place. I've pushed a fix to production that rectifies this.

Comment: Now the stack exchange icon is not displaying in the your communities, so no more issue with the tooltip